# migration problem VS2005 -> VS2010 - missing assembly reference error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, migration

I recently migrated a solution from VS2005 to VS2010.
The solution is composed by about 20 project. One of them is in VB.net, the others are C#.
In VS2005 everything was fine, that is I was able to reference the VB.net project into the C Sharp projects. Now I cannot anymore.
The strange thing is that when I open in the editor a C# class referencing the VB.net dll, I get a compile error that sounds more or less like this:
"he type or namespace name 'VB.netProject' does not exist in the namespace 'Solution Namespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

... and no, the assembly reference is there indeed!

However, when I close the files in the editor and try to compile again, the operation succeeds and the executable that I get works perfectly like it did in VS2005.

Is there a way I can manage to see the VB.net component in the editor? I am sure I am missing something, but I don't know what! :-)

Many thanks in advance for your help,

John

Comment: You have all the Visual Studio Componenents installed on both versions? You are able to make a simple mixed langauge solution from fresh?

Comment: You probably haven't installed VS2010 with VB.NET support. You can fix that by running the VS2010 installer, choosing to modify your installation, and then checking the VB.NET language support box.

Comment: In replying to both: I did install the full VS2010 with all components and there is VB.net support indeed. The VB.net project compiles properly in VS2010, I just cannot see it under C# projects in the same solution. Thanks a lot. John

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the visual studio sets (after the migration) the target framework to .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. If this target framework is set, some namespace could not be found (=> because the client profile doesn't contain this classes). Please verify, if your project has set this target framework. You will find this setting under the project properties.

Kind regards, patrick

Comment: Hello Patrick, I checked the target framework and it is 2.0. I set that manually a few days ago in order to overcome deploying problems (not all the customer machines have .net 4 installed). So this makes things more complicated I guess. Thanks for your help, John

Comment: Dear All,It seems that I found a solution. What I did was to tick the setting "Register For Com Interoperability" to true and now I can see the VB project under the C# projects. Thanks a lot to you all for the help received. John